# Using "got" in present tense?

Tags: past-vs-present

> They set unbelievably hard tasks to do, to see which one of us *got* the best deal. - *Top Gear* (TV show)

I don't understand; what is "got" doing in present tense? Or am I misunderstanding the sentence?

Comment: You might want to check out [ell.se], where no one ever needs to apologize for their English. :^)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Got* is past tense and it’s perfectly grammatical. That’s because *set* is also past tense, although, because it’s the same as the present tense, it doesn’t show as such.

Imagine that the verb was instead *gave*, which **is** different from the present tense:

> They gave us unbelievably hard tasks to do to see which one of us
>   ***_*___**  the best deal.

The only conventionally grammatical way to fill the gap is with *got*.